# How to make function that works with await but also can take callback?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create a function that can work with both async/await and usual callback pattern. so something like the following would work:

```
function myFunc(cb) {
   setTimeout(function(){   //something async
       console.log('hello');
       cb();
   });
}

myFunc(function(){
   console.log('world');
});
```

but what is below won't work

```
function myFunc(cb = function(){}) {
   setTimeout(function(){   //something async
       console.log('hello');
       cb();
   }, 1000);
}

(async ()=> {
     await myFunc();
     console.log('world');
})();
```

I understand for `await` to work `myFunc` needs to return a promise and even though i've few ideas in mind on how to take callback and return promise, I'd like to see some proper way to do this.

Comment: Typically when I see this in libraries, the function takes 2 parameters with the second being the callback, and if that parameter is omitted, it will return a promise instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use both like this

```
function myFunc (giveback, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
           resolve(giveback);
           if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(null, giveback);
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: That will result in a runtime error due to `callback` might not be passed. I.e `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the way to achieve this is to check the amount of arguments explicitly passed, and act accordingly.

If you want `myFunc()` to achieve both styles simultaneously, here's a possible implementation:

```js
function myFunc(cb) {
  // some async logic
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // pass some value here
      resolve('success')
    }, 1000)

    setTimeout(() => {
      // pass some error here
      reject(new Error('something broke'))
    }, Math.random() * 2000) // 50% chance of failure
  })

  if (arguments.length < 1) {
    // invoked promise-style
    return p
  } else if (typeof cb === 'function') {
    // invoked callback-style with valid function
    p.then(result => { cb(null, result) }, error => { cb(error) })
  } else {
    // invoking in callback-style with a non-function
    // should produce a fatal error
    throw new TypeError('cb is not a function')
  }
}

// usage

try {
  // invalid invocation without function parameter
  myFunc('strings do not implement [[Call]]')
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message)
}

// callback-style
myFunc((error, value) => {
  if (error) return console.log(`callback with error: ${error.message}`)
  console.log(`callback with value: ${value}`)
})

// promise-style
myFunc().then(value => {
  console.log(`promise with value: ${value}`)
}, error => {
  console.log(`promise with error: ${error.message}`)
})
```

The above implementation intentionally does not return a promise when invoked with a callback. If you *want* it to do so, then I recommend this approach, as it's a little more flexible (i.e. if you want to pass a callback and still treat it as a then-able):

```js
function myFunc(cb = () => {}) {
  if (arguments.length > 0 && typeof cb !== 'function') {
    // invoking in callback-style with a non-function
    // should produce a fatal error
    throw new TypeError('cb is not a function')
  }

  // some async logic
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // pass some value here
      resolve('success')
    }, 1000)

    setTimeout(() => {
      // pass some error here
      reject(new Error('something broke'))
    }, Math.random() * 2000) // 50% chance of failure
  }).then(result => {
    cb(null, result)
    // propagate result
    return result
  }, error => {
    cb(error)
    // propagate error
    throw error
  })
}

// usage

try {
  // invalid invocation without function parameter
  myFunc('strings do not implement [[Call]]')
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message)
}

// callback-style
myFunc((error, value) => {
  if (error) return console.log(`callback with error: ${error.message}`)
  console.log(`callback with value: ${value}`)
})

// promise-style
myFunc().then(value => {
  console.log(`promise with value: ${value}`)
}, error => {
  console.log(`promise with error: ${error.message}`)
})

// using both styles
myFunc((error, value) => {
  if (error) return console.log(`mixed callback with error: ${error.message}`)
  console.log(`mixed callback with value: ${value}`)
}).then(value => {
  console.log(`mixed promise with value: ${value}`)
}, error => {
  console.log(`mixed promise with error: ${error.message}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional example of what I described earlier:

```
const myFunc = (obj, callback) => {
    if (!callback) {
        const performWork = async () => obj
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const value = await performWork()
            resolve(value)
        })
    }
    const cb = obj
    callback(cb)
}

const test = { test: 1337 }

// Promise version
myFunc(test)
    .then((res) => console.log('Promise version', res))

// Callback version
myFunc(test, (res) => {
    console.log('Callback version', res)
})
```